# переключатель языков сайта

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

есть Htlm страница , на ней имеется две кнопки ru и en , собственно как реализовать  переключение языков страницы ? делать вторую html но уже в английском варианте и указать ссылку на английскую версию страницы html ? но по мне это очень не верный вариант похоже скорее всего .
нужно так что бы был маяк похоже , а именно в адресной строке адрес/ru допустим .
подскажите какие варианты правильные сейчас используются

Comment: Есть различные варианты реализации. Можно отдельную страницу создать и переключать между ними с помощью JavaScript, можно использовать различные адреса (субдомены) для каждого из языков.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov какой из способов проще в реализации , и может есть примеры ?

Comment: Нет точного ответа на этот вопрос. Если вы погуглите, то найдете массу плюсов и минусов в каждой реализации. Вам надо только выбрать, что вам подходит.